# Can users connected to the same non-open (e.g. WPA-PSK) WiFi see each others traffic?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, encryption

I understand that users connected to the same open WiFi can see each others traffic, since it is send in plaintext; this even holds for users not connected to the WiFi.

However, Wikipedia states that the encryption key in WPA-PSK is derived from the passphrase, that all users must know to connect to the WiFi. So, all users derive and use the same encryption key?

In other words, all users that connect to the same WPA-PSK WiFi can see each others traffic, and only users not connected to the WiFi are unable to see the traffic?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access

> Each wireless network device encrypts the network traffic by deriving
>   its 128-bit encryption key from a 256 bit shared key. This key may be
>   entered either as a string of 64 hexadecimal digits, or as a
>   passphrase of 8 to 63 printable ASCII characters.[16] If ASCII
>   characters are used, the 256 bit key is calculated by applying the
>   PBKDF2 key derivation function to the passphrase, using the SSID as
>   the salt and 4096 iterations of HMAC-SHA1.[17] WPA-Personal mode is
>   available with both WPA and WPA2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the passphrase or PSK of a given WPA-PSK or WPA2-PSK network, AND you capture the key handshake when a given client joins the network, you can decrypt that client’s traffic for that session (until it disconnects from and reconnects to the AP, at which time you’ll need to capture its new key handshake in order to get the info that allows you to decrypt that client’s new session).

The clients all use the same passphrase, which gets hashed via PBKDF2 into the Pairwise Master Key (PMK), but the clients don’t encrypt with the PMK directly. At the start of a connection, the client and AP each generate a random number called a nonce and send them to each other, and these nonces are used along with the PMK to derive the key that that client will use for that session to encrypt its traffic. The AP derives the same key and uses it to encrypt all the traffic for that one client for that one session.

Edited to add: So clients can’t automatically decrypt each others’ traffic on a WPA-PSK network like they could in the days of WEP, but with very little extra work, any device within range of the network, who knows the passphrase, can decrypt the clients’ network traffic. The attacker does not even need to be connected to the network. He just needs to be in range and know the passphrase.

Comment: thank you for an excellent answer. The Wikipedia page doesn't mention the nonces (see my snippet)? Also, the PSK is derived from the passphrase right (8-63 ASCII char)? Otherwise, it is directly inputted using 64 hex char?

Comment: So, the 128-bit key derived from the PMK (password + PBKDF2) and nonces are shared between the AP and client and is unique for this pair? The cipher used is symmetric shared-key?

Comment: @user111854 Yes. The passphrase plus the SSID (and maybe a salt?) go through PBKDF2 to form the PSK a.k.a. PMK. The PMK plus the nonces allow you to derive a Pairwise Transient Key (PTK) which is 64 bytes (512 bits) and gets divided into several other keys, one of which is the 128-bit Temporal Key that gets used with AES-CCMP (in the case of WPA2) for encrypting unicast data frames to/from that one client for that one session. See the [Wikipedia article for 802.11i](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11i-2004).

Comment: Thank you - last question, what is a "unicast" data frame? I know of multicast packets.

Comment: @user111854 Unicast traffic is normal traffic addressed to a single host. We say unicast when we want to call out that we’re not including multicast or broadcast in whatever we’re discussing.

Comment: Thanks again - I've accepted your great answer. Multicast and broadcast traffic is the same thing, right?